# How to point my domain (myapp.com) to app running on vps with ip address?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, hosting, vps, bind9

i want when client in the browser type my domain name it shows app running on port 80 of my vps.

all i have now is one registered domain name , in the manage panel of it i can edit name servers ( two name servers) .
and i have one vps with one static ip address ,
i can see my app in browser if i type ip address of my vps , but i want to connect my domain name to this service on port 80 of my vps.

i think i should register two name server (dns) in my vps . but don't know how to do it .
i don't want locally , i want to make sure it works on all of the world (internet users) access my website.

i don't have any cpanel or admin-panel . i want to do it myself and not use some kind of panels  ...

i am new to this area ... )

Answer (score 0):

you need only to configure your domain name to this ipaddress:port